# Why is my vertex painting sometimes working and sometimes not working?

Tags: vertex-paint, vertex-paint-mode

I'm vertex painting another texture onto my mesh plane, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

[image]

There are solid black lines in the background, the vertex painting works as expected. However, in some areas, when I paint, it creates this jagged random pattern instead of a solid black line. And this is the result, instead of the texture, it just leaves the black instead. Compare the areas in which there is a solid black line, compared to this jagged pattern area. You'll notice that the texture is applied in the solid black line area, but not the messed up area:

[image]

How do I fix this? Or, what causes this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vertex Paint gives color to your vertex, so it completely depends on your topology, are you sure that your topology is not completely messed up on these parts? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots it's a little raised there but I don't think the topology is messed up. only where it's a little higher it starts doing this for some reason. also I couldn't upload it to that site because 24mb was the maximum file size

Comment: could you at least share this particular part?

Comment: @moonboots how do I do that?

Comment: just save your file as a new file, delete all the objects except your ground, in Edit mode delete a large part of your ground and only keep the part with the problem, then share

Comment: @moonboots Sorry, took so long had to delete some terrain too, here it is now: https://pasteall.org/blend/4b1d63283649446d85b8307a689f82c1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object's scale is very stretched, apply it in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), it will probably help to correctly vertex paint:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't do that, it works now